# Set image data into image src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that gets the image data on click, the image data is defined as a variable, what i want to do is to take this image data and set it into an image src, how can i do that? here is my code:

```js
    $('.export').click(function() {
      var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src=''>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `attr()` function:

```
$('img').attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData)
```

See more about the function - http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: The image data returns the base64 for the image i want to take it and put it into another image src, you answered half of my question

Answer (score 1):

Try jquery [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Update your image element `<img id='profile-pic' src=''>`

```
$('.export').click(function() {
    var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
    $('#profile-pic').attr('src', imageData); //Change your img src to imageData
});
```

**Update 1: For `base64`**

```
$('#profile-pic').attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData);
```

Comment: The image data returns the base64 for the image i want to take it and put it into another image src, you answered half of my question

Comment: Updated the answer for `base64`. Copied from @BubbleHacker.